# Flat view in Finder - does it exist?

Tags: finder

I have seen this useful feature in several Windows File Explorer clones - the flat view. Basically the feature allows you to view all the files in the current directory and sub-directories, side-by-side, as if they were all in the same directory. Useful when trying to compare/find files. I don't think it exists in Finder, but what about the various Finder replacements?

[Showsize Flat View Example](http://showsize.com/list-all-folders-in-one-list-in-windows.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotlight can, if you just search for "-kind:folder".
It also shows the files. It looks like a bug to me, but it works.

Found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26365/how-to-create-a-spotlight-search-for-all-files-inside-a-folder).